# Как создать статический sprite.svg, используя webpack?

Tags: svg, webpack, спрайт

Помогите написать конфиг для создания файла спрайта в webpack. Пытаюсь разобраться с вот этим плагином -> https://github.com/kisenka/svg-sprite-loader/ , но прям не понимаю как оно работает :(

Нужно чтобы из папки **img/icons-svg/** по итогу генерировался файл **img/sprite_build.svg**

Вот код из конфига:

```
...
{
      test: /\.svg$/,
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/img/icons-svg'),
      loader: 'svg-sprite-loader',
      options: {
          extract: true,
          publicPath: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/img/'),
          spriteFilename: 'sprite_build.svg'
      }

  }
  ...
  plugins: [
     new SpriteSvgPlugin({plainSprite: true}), 
      ...
  ]
```

Но спрайт не создается. Хотя в консоли при сборке, видно что он находит файлы из **/icons-svg/** что-то с ними делает, но файл не генерирует.

*Если есть другие решения, кроме это плагина -- они тоже принимаются, если что.*

Answer (score 1):

Наткнулся на такой тред в гитхабе, по [ссылке](https://github.com/JetBrains/svg-sprite-loader/issues/212#issuecomment-343664035) корректный ответ.

Если коротко, то можно использовать вот такую зависимость:

```
const glob = require('glob').sync;

module.exports = {
   entry: {
      sprite: glob('./source/assets/images/icons/*.svg')
   },
   module: {...},
   plugins: [...]
};
```